# Invalid paths in urls.py

Tags: python, django

When I run my server I receive an error saying that all my url paths are invalid. I checked spelling, syntax, and even copy and pasted to no avail. I just want it to run.

I attempted to correct my spelling, Syntax, everything.

I'm running a simple Django server on a Raspberry Pi 3 B

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name="index"),
    path('suggest/', views.OwO, name="OwO"),
]
```

I also tried

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name="index"),
    path('suggest', views.OwO, name="OwO"),
]
```

My views

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from .forms import suggest
from .models improt message

# Create your views here.

def index(request):
    form = suggest()
    return render(request, 'index.html' {'form':form})

def OwO(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = sugest(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            name = form.cleaned_data['name']
            UwU = form.cleaned_data['messgae']
            a = message(form_name=name, form_message=UwU)
            a.save()
            return HttpResponse("Thank you " + name + "!")
    else:
       Return HttpResponse("OwO")
```

The Exception:

```
Watching for file changes with StatReloader
Performing system checks...

Exception in thread django-main-thread:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 581, in url_patterns
    iter(patterns)
TypeError: 'module' object is not iterable

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/threading.py", line 914, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/threading.py", line 862, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 54, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 117, in inner_run
    self.check(display_num_errors=True)
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 390, in check
    include_deployment_checks=include_deployment_checks,
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 377, in _run_checks
    return checks.run_checks(**kwargs)
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/checks/registry.py", line 72, in run_checks
    new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs)
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/checks/urls.py", line 40, in check_url_namespaces_unique
    all_namespaces = _load_all_namespaces(resolver)
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/checks/urls.py", line 57, in _load_all_namespaces
    url_patterns = getattr(resolver, 'url_patterns', [])
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 80, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 588, in url_patterns
    raise ImproperlyConfigured(msg.format(name=self.urlconf_name))
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: The included URLconf 'Suggest.urls' does not appear to have any patterns in it. If you see valid patterns in the file then the issue is probably caused by a circular import.
```

Comment: Show the exact error you got.

Comment: Show your views, too.

Comment: @Jay Ok, Just added the edit

Comment: Please, share the traceback of the exception you get

Comment: @HuLuViCa done, but I'm not sure if its going to help :/

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that this code is running?

I can see some mistakes like `Return`(must be lowercase) or `sugest`(missing one letter g).

Comment: Everything but the last line (Because I copied it from Emacs on terminal and it got cut off, so the ```Return``` wasn't apart of the code). I also attempted to run a simple app with the exact same issue.

Comment: @Raccoondude Where exactly did you put your routes? I mean, which file and where is it located?

Comment: Same directory as url.py, if i'm reading the question correctly, your asking where I put the scripts for the app

Comment: I don't see what could be the issue. Post the html template. Maybe there is an error there regarding a route.